# How to process list of numbers(arrays) in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, numbers

I have a list of multiple consecutive numbers. I am trying to figure it out how to know the number of increase or decrease in relation to to past value . For example

```
102, 201, 198, 200
```

That is **2** increase (`102, 201` and `198, 200`) and **1** decrease (`201, 198`). It is a long list of number so manual is tedious. I am a beginner  using C#.

Comment: What have you been tried? Could you, please, show your attempt (code)?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways, from *querying* with help of *Linq*:

```
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  int[] source = new int[] { 102, 201, 198, 200 }; 

  ...

  // Probably, the most generic approach
  var result = source.Aggregate(
    (Inc: 0, Dec: 0, prior: (int?)null),
    (s, a) => (s.Inc + (s.prior < a ? 1 : 0), s.Dec + (s.prior > a ? 1 : 0), a));

  Console.Write($"Increasing: {result.Inc}; decreasing: {result.Dec}");
```

up to good old `for` loop:

```
  int Inc = 0;
  int Dec = 0;

  // Probably, the easiest to understand solution
  for (int i = 1; i < source.Length; ++i)
    if (source[i - 1] > source[i])
      Dec += 1;
    else if (source[i - 1] < source[i])
      Inc += 1;  

  Console.Write($"Increasing: {Inc}; decreasing: {Dec}");
```

**Edit:** Linq `Aggregate` explained.

```
  Aggregate(
    (Inc: 0, Dec: 0, prior: (int?)null),
    (s, a) => (s.Inc + (s.prior < a ? 1 : 0), s.Dec + (s.prior > a ? 1 : 0), a));
```

In order to obtain single value from a cursor, we use `Aggregate`.

First argument

```
  (Inc: 0, Dec: 0, prior: (int?)null)
```

is the initial value (*named tuple*, to combine several properties in one instance). Here we have `0` increasing and decreasing and `null` for the previous item.

Second argument

```
  (s, a) => (s.Inc + (s.prior < a ? 1 : 0), s.Dec + (s.prior > a ? 1 : 0), a)
```

Is a rule how to add a next item `a` to aggregated items `s`. We should

1. Increment `s.Inc` in case `prior` item is smaller than current `a`: `s.Inc + (s.prior < a ? 1 : 0)`
2. Increment `s.Dec` in case `prior` item is bigger than current `a`: `s.Dec + (s.prior > a ? 1 : 0)`
3. We should assign current item `a` as the next `prior` element.

Let's put it a bit *wordy* but I hope more readable:

```
.Aggregate(
   (Inc: 0,           // no increasing 
    Dec: 0,           // no decreasing
    prior: (int?)null // no prior item
   ),
   (s, a) => ( // s - partial aggregation, a - to add item
      Inc:   s.Inc + (s.prior < a ? 1 : 0), // Increment Inc if required
      Dec:   s.Dec + (s.prior > a ? 1 : 0), // Increment Dec if required 
      prior: a                              // Set a as a prior  
   )
 )
```

Hope, now it's clearer what's going under the hood of `Aggregate`

Comment: Can you break down the linq expression please? I'm having trouble understanding it from this page I googled: https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/213/using-c-linq---a-practical-overview/aggregate

Comment: @butterflyknife: I've edited the answer, `Aggregate`  explanation added

Comment: Thank you so much. Would upvote twice if I could :-) Bookmarked for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you can use a [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_for_loop.php):

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfNumbers.Length; i++)
{
    int currentEntry = listOfNumbers [i];
    if(i > 0){
        int previousEntry = listOfNumbers [i - 1];
        Console.Log("Change from previous : " + (currentEntry-previousEntry));
    }else{
        Console.Log("No previous entry so no change can be found.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int[] source = new int[] { 102, 201, 198, 200 };
    int Increment = 0;
    int Decrement= 0;
    int k;
    for (k=1; k< array.length; k++)
    if (array[k - 1] > array[k])
      Decrement++;
    else 
    {
    if (array[k - 1] < array[k])
      Increment++;  
    }

  Console.Write("Increasing: {Increment}, decreasing: {Decrement}");
   }
```